# How does a computer reproduce the SIFT paper method on its own in deep learning

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

Let me begin by saying that I am struggling to understand what is going on in deep learning. From what I gather, it is an approach to try to have a computer engineer different layers  of representations and features to enable it learn stuff on its own.  SIFT seems to be a common way to sort of detect things by tagging and hunting for scale invariant things in some representation. Again I am completely stupid and in awe and wonder about how this magic is achieved. How does one have a computer do this by itself? I have looked at this paper https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf and I must say at this point I think it is magic. Can somebody help me distill the main points of how this works and why a computer can do it on its own?

Comment: A computer cannot do it completely on its own, it learns from data that is labeled by a human, and with a neural network that is also designed by a human. SIFT has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Please clarify where you're having trouble: is it with DL (deep learning) in general, or the SIFT application in particular?  Please note that this is likely off-topic for SO (StackOverflow); this is not a tutorial site.  However, if your specific question fits into our general guidelines, I'll take a shot at it.  I've been explaining DL to friends and family for a couple of months now.

Answer (score 0):

SIFT and CNN are both methods to extract features from images in different ways and outputs.

SIFT/SURF/ORB or any similar feature extraction algorithms are "Hand-made" feature extraction algorithms. It means, independent from the real world cases, they are aiming to extract some meaningful features. This approach has some advantages and disadvantages.

Advantages :

- You don't have to care about input image conditions and probably you don't need any pre-processing step to extract those features.
- You can directly get SIFT implementation and integrate it to your application
- With GPU based implementations (i.e. GPU-SIFT), you can achieve high inference speed.

Disadvantages:

- It has limitation about finding the features. You will have trouble about getting features over quite plain surfaces.
- SIFT/SURF/ORB cannot solve all problems that requires feature classification / matching. Think face recognition problem. Do you think that extracting & classifying SIFT features over face will be enough to recognize people?
- Those are hand-made feature extraction techniques, they cannot be improved over time (of course unless a better technique is being introduced)
- Developing such a feature extraction technique requires a lot of research work

In the other hand, in deep learning, you can start analyzing much complex features which are impossible by human to recognize. CNNs are perfect approach as today to analyze hierarchical filter responses and much complex features which are created by combining those filter responses (going deeper). 
The main power of CNNs are coming from not extracting features by hand. We only define "how" PC has to look for features. Of course this method has some pros and cons too.

Advantages :

- More data, better success! It is all depending on data. If you have enough data to explain your case, DL outperforms hand-made feature extraction techniques.
- As soon as you extract the features from image, you can use it for many purposes like to segment image, to create description words, to detect objects inside image, to recognize them. The better part is, all of them can be obtained in one shot, rather than complex sequential processes.

Disadvantages:

- You need data. Probably a lot.
- It is better to use supervised or reinforcement learning methods in these days. As unsupervised learning is still not good enough yet.
- It takes time and resource to train a good neural net. A complex hierarchy like Google Inception took 2 weeks to be trained on 8 GPU server rack. Of course not all the networks are so hard to train.
- It has some learning curve. You don't have to know how SIFT is working to use it for your application but you have to know how CNNs are working to use them in your custom purposes.